# Modify WFS with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I want to edit object on WFS layer but have one problem. I use `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(myVecLayer)` to editing.By the logic i do this.

1. Press button and create WFS layer with chosen object
2. Add `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature` to map controls  and activate
   this
3. Edit object
4. Press button again and remove WFS layer with
   my object, deactivate `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature` control.
5. Select next object (or same object) and do "1", "2"

   And object not editing.
   But if I do not remove layer after editing, but just add new WFS layer to map `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature` control works

My code:

```
function ff(){
if(counter==0){
    //WFS
        var myStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend({},
                                OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
                            myStyle.strokeWidth = 1.5;
                            myStyle.strokeColor = "#ff0000";
                            myStyle.fillOpacity = 0.1;
                            OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
                            var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
                            renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;           
                            myVecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Редактируемый участок", {
                                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save()],
                                style: myStyle,
                                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                                    version: "1.0.0",
                                    srsName:"EPSG:900913",
                                    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                                    featureType: "filedata",
                                    featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
                                    defaultFilter : new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                                        property: 'id',
                                        value: "162",
                                    })
                                }),
                                renderers: renderer
                            })  
                            map.addLayers([myVecLayer]);


                            if(ppp==null){
                                if (edit==null){
                                    edit = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(myVecLayer);
                                    map.addControl(edit);
                                    ppp=map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature");
                                }

                                alert(ppp);
                            }
                        //  ppp.autoActivate=true;
                            for(var i=0;i<ppp.length;i++){
                                ppp[i].activate();
                                alert("2 "+ppp[i].active);
                            }

                            counter=1;

                }
```

Its will nice if u help.

Comment: Or can someone tell me how to make new filter to WFS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I find answer to my question. Just need to use filters.

```
//WFS
                            var myStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend({},
                                OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
                            myStyle.strokeWidth = 1.5;
                            myStyle.strokeColor = "#ff0000";
                            myStyle.fillOpacity = 0.1;
                            OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
                            var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
                            renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;           
                            myVecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Редактируемый участок", {
                                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), SS],
                                style: myStyle,
                                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                                    version: "1.0.0",
                                    srsName:"EPSG:900913",
                                    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                                    featureType: "filedata",
                                    featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
                                    defaultFilter : filter
                                }),
                                renderers: renderer
                            })
```

Filters+Editing

```
if(counter==0){
                    if(ppp==null){
                                if (edit==null){
                                    edit = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(myVecLayer);
                                    map.addControl(edit);
                                    ppp=map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature");
                                }
                            }

                                map.addLayers([myVecLayer]);
                                Ffilter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                                        property: 'id',
                                        value: '170',
                                    })
                                myVecLayer.filter=Ffilter;
                                myVecLayer.refresh({force: true});
                            for(var i=0;i<ppp.length;i++){
                                ppp[i].activate();
                            }
                            counter=1;

                }
                else {
                    //FS.deactivate();
                //  SS.save();
                    //myVecLayer.destroyFeatures(); 
                    map.removeLayer(myVecLayer); 
                    for(var i=0;i<ppp.length;i++){
                                ppp[i].deactivate();
                            }
                    //ppp.deactivate();
                    counter=0;
                }
```