# How to edit feature attributes with openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I want to edit object's attributes on WFS layer. I see this example http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/styles_unique_with_group_wfs.html but popup is horrible. I want to use ExtJs form to editing.
So how to edit attributes in this case?

Comment: Do you know in advance what the feature attributes will be, or do you need to build the form dynamically?

Comment: I know what attributes get in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first need to create `store`

```
                          st = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
                                    layer: myVecLayer,
                                    fields: [
                                        {name: 'id', type: 'int'}
                                    ],
                                     proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
                                        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                                            version: "1.0.0",
                                            srsName:"EPSG:900913",
                                            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                                            featureType: "filedata_temp",
                                            featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
                                            filter:Ffilter
                                        })
                                    }),
                                    autoLoad: true
                                });
```

Then EditorGrid

```
    var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
                columns: [
                    {header: "id", 
                     dataIndex:"id",
                     editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: false})
                    }]
    })


var ed_tab = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                store: st,
                region: 'center',
                    cm: cm,
                height: 200,
                title:'Аттрибуты',
                    autoScroll: true,
                bbar:[{
                     xtype: 'tbbutton',
                     cls: 'x-btn-icon',
                     tooltip: "Сделать что то",
                     id: "something",
                     icon: url_servlet+'externals/gxp/src/theme/img/silk/delete.png',
                     handler: function(){
                                        ed_tab.store.proxy.protocol.commit(
                                               myVecLayer.features
                                          );
                                        ed_tab.store.reload();
                                    }
                    }]
                })


var x = new Ext.Window({
        title:'Аттрибуты',
        items:[ed_tab]  
        })
 x.show();
```

That all about attributes. To modifity geometry htere: [Modify WFS with OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/modify-wfs-with-openlayers)