# Save WFS layers multiple records with geoext editor grid

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, geoext, fields-attributes, editing

How can I save multiple records after modification with geoext editor grid?
The saving is working fine if I modify only one of the records, but it fails when I try to save multiple modifications.

I used this geoext solution to modify the attributes of my wfs layer: 
[How to edit feature attributes with openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/how-to-edit-feature-attributes-with-openlayers).