# building forms dynamically

Tags: openlayers

I found this previous post [How to edit feature attributes with openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/how-to-edit-feature-attributes-with-openlayers) and wanted to make forms dynamically.

I tried making a variable and using a getProperties function but that didn't make the form as a popup.

Any suggestions on how to generate these forms based on a featuretype WFS request from Geoserver in Openlayers?

```
    value: function _onDrawEnd(evt) {
  var attributes = this._layer.getProperties();
  var wfsInfo = this._layer.get('wfsInfo');
   st = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
                                layer: this._layer,
                                fields: [attributes],
```